# Play Integrity API state Integration started

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile, google-play-integrity-api

I want to integrate the Google Play Integrity API. I just want to integrate it. I am not going to use any feature of this API. So, I wanna know that enabling the API is enough or not? I enabled the API, but the current status is "Integration started". In the other projects the status is "Integration active". Do I need to do something to switch the status from "started" to "active"?

[image]

Entegrasyon Başladı = Integration started

Answer (score 2):

From Google Play support:

> The play console may still require a certain number of requests among the users that are already using your app with this service in order for the system to recognize and process the data to the Play console UI (which resolves the pending checklist). Furthermore, please also note we are currently not surfacing the standard mode data on the reporting page via Play console. The Reporting page only shows data corresponding to classic mode requests.

So your app needs to make some number of calls to the [Classic API](https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity/classic) before the Play Console registers that you are using it.

If you are using the new [Standard API](https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity/standard) (which came out of beta in Novemeber 2023) then the Play Console does not yet support those calls, so it will continue to say 'integration started' until they add support to the Console.